# Correct way to show various possible parameters for selection by user, when running Script from inside a ERP system

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case, where-clause

[This is sample data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=29626702457509858340)

[Report_parameters](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=79492278758069143949)

I'm currently designing a SQL report, to be run from inside a ERP system.
The idea behind this code, is to bring all AR open items, with all these fields in SELECT stamement, and be able to chose which to run report for, by the various WHERE clauses options that I describe.

I enclose as well, the table inside ERP system, with "parameters" names, and the options user will have to run report as...

I'm not able to get all these CASE & OR statement to work, or provide specific data, based on search criteria.

I'm not even sure I'm showing the parameters correctly on the WHERE clause code (with the "< >", or by field name, or with ' ', ...)

I'm not such an advanced user with SQL, so I ask for your assistance, as I'm sure you will have more straight forward ways to design this report.

[System defined parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52xiW.png)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
e1.rel_value AS Cust_Rep_Grp, 
o1.description AS Cust_Rep_Grp_Name, 
r.main_apar_id AS Head_Office, 
o2.description AS Head_Office_Name, 
s.apar_id AS CustID, 
o3.description AS Cust_ID_Name, 
s.voucher_no, 
s.dim_2 AS BookingNo, 
h.ext_ord_ref AS YourRef,  
n.booking_day_fx AS Booking_date, 
n.check_in_date_fx AS Check_in_date, 
n.check_out_date_fx AS Check_out_date, 
s.voucher_date AS Invoice_date,
s.due_date, 
i.art_descr AS Hotel_name, 
o.description AS Destination,
e2.rel_value AS City,
o.description AS City_name,
e.rel_value AS Country_code,
o4.description AS Country_name, 
n.guest_fx AS Client_name,
n.pax_fx, 
s.currency,
i.disc_percent AS Comm_percentage, 
s.cur_amount AS Net_amt, 
s.rest_curr AS Due_now,
s.voucher_type,
s.order_id 
FROM acutrans s
LEFT OUTER JOIN acuheader r
ON r.client = s.client
AND s.apar_id = r.apar_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN asoheader h
ON h.client = s.client
AND h.order_id = s.order_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN asodetail i
ON i.client = s.client
AND i.order_id = s.order_id
INNER JOIN algvirelvalue e2 
ON e2.client= s.client 
AND e2.rel_attr_id='ZZ06'
AND e2.related_attr = 'CITY' 
AND i.article = e2.article
LEFT OUTER JOIN aglrelvalue e 
ON e.client= s.client 
AND e.attribute_id = 'ZZ06'
AND e.rel_attr_id = 'C9'
AND e.att_value = e2.rel_value
LEFT OUTER JOIN aglrelvalue e1
ON e1.client = s.client
AND e1.attribute_id = 'A4'
AND e1.rel_attr_id = 'ZG06'
AND e1.att_value = s.apar_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN agldescription o 
ON o.client= s.client 
AND o.attribute_id='ZZ06' 
AND o.dim_value = e2.rel_value
LEFT OUTER JOIN agldescription o1 
ON o1.client= s.client 
AND o1.attribute_id='ZG06' 
AND o1.dim_value = e1.rel_value
LEFT OUTER JOIN agldescription o2 
ON o2.client= s.client 
AND o2.attribute_id='A4' 
AND o2.dim_value = r.main_apar_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN agldescription o3 
ON o3.client= s.client 
AND o3.attribute_id='A4' 
AND o3.dim_value = s.apar_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN agldescription o4 
ON o4.client= s.client 
AND o4.attribute_id='C9' 
AND o4.dim_value = e.rel_value
LEFT OUTER JOIN afxbooking_gen n 
ON s.dim_2 = n.dim_value 
AND s.client = n.client 
AND n.attribute_id = 'ZZ01'

WHERE  
      CASE WHEN '<checkin_from>' IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE '<checkin_from>' END LIKE n.check_in_date_fx
      AND  
      CASE WHEN n.check_in_date_fx IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE n.check_in_date_fx END LIKE n.check_in_date_fx
      OR
      CASE WHEN s.voucher_date IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.voucher_date END LIKE s.voucher_Date
      AND 
      CASE WHEN s.voucher_date IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.voucher_date END LIKE s.voucher_Date
      OR 
      CASE WHEN n.booking_day_fx IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE n.booking_day_fx END LIKE n.booking_day_fx
      AND
      CASE WHEN n.booking_day_fx IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE n.booking_day_fx END LIKE n.booking_day_fx
      OR 
      CASE WHEN n.check_out_date_fx IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE n.check_out_date_fx END LIKE n.check_out_date_fx
      AND 
      CASE WHEN n.check_out_date_fx IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE n.check_out_date_fx END LIKE n.check_out_date_fx  
      OR 
      CASE WHEN s.apar_id  IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.apar_id  END LIKE s.apar_id 
      AND
      CASE WHEN s.apar_id  IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.apar_id  END LIKE s.apar_id 
      OR 
      CASE WHEN o3.description IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE o3.description END LIKE o3.description
      OR 
      CASE WHEN e1.rel_value IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE e1.rel_value END LIKE e1.rel_value
      AND
      CASE WHEN e1.rel_value IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE e1.rel_value END LIKE e1.rel_value
      OR 
      CASE WHEN o1.description IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE o1.description END LIKE o1.description 
      OR 
      CASE WHEN r.main_apar_id IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE r.main_apar_id END LIKE r.main_apar_id
      AND
      CASE WHEN r.main_apar_idIN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE r.main_apar_id END LIKE r.main_apar_id
      OR 
      CASE WHEN o2.description IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE o2.description END LIKE o2.description  
      OR 
      CASE WHEN s.dim_2 IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.dim_2 END LIKE s.dim_2
      AND
      CASE WHEN s.dim_2 IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.dim_2 END LIKE s.dim_2
      OR 
      CASE WHEN e.rel_value IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE e.rel_value END LIKE e.rel_value  
      OR 
      CASE WHEN s.currency  IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.currency  END LIKE s.currency  
      OR 
      CASE WHEN n.guest_fx IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE n.guest_fx END LIKE n.guest_fx 
      OR 
      CASE WHEN s.voucher_no IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.voucher_no END LIKE s.voucher_no
      AND
      CASE WHEN s.voucher_no IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.voucher_no END LIKE s.voucher_no
      OR 
      CASE WHEN h.ext_ord_ref IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE h.ext_ord_ref END LIKE h.ext_ord_ref
      OR 
      CASE WHEN s.order_id IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.order_id END LIKE s.order_id
      AND
      CASE WHEN s.order_id IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.order_id END LIKE s.order_id
```

Any suggestions, maybe different way to build all script together, something more simpler to show same thing, any experties from yourselves, is really much appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: The "sample data" link, takes you to an excel spreadsheet, with respective formats. The image link is just how report parameters are set as.

Comment: _all as formatted text, not images_

Comment: Done. It's the new link "Report Parameters". Thank you